# Creating threaded nodes

Tags: 7, nodes

I know with Drupal you can have threaded comments. I wish to create something similar using nodes.

Where a node can be replied to with a node of the same type. I would then like to try and create a view of this. Do you think this is possible or should I look at bending comments to be more like nodes.

Comment: Do you want to use nodes as comments, or simply visualize nodes as threaded nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like [Node comments](http://drupal.org/project/nodecomment) to me. With it you can use normal Contentypes as comments. There is already a view included in the module.