# A view of full nodes with comments that are a content type

Tags: views, 7

I have split up this question into other questions previously trying to join them up to create my final solution. However the combination of what I am trying is causing problems.

I need a comment field to be able to use a CCK field. To do this I am using the nodecomment module as it allows you to use a content type for comment (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/creating-threaded-nodes). I will call this type CustomComment.

I have a custom node type, NodeType. This uses CustomComment for it's comments.

I need to create a view of NodeType. Which prints the full node (not fields). I also need to print the Comments as full nodes as well. Can anyone give any additional pointers. Part of me is thinking It might be better for me code this myself.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind:

1. make a view for the nodeTypes
2. make a view for the customComments
3. take the corresponding view-template (depends on your views, check the views theme-information) of the nodeTypes-view and render the customComments-view inside it using [views_embed_view()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--views.module/function/views_embed_view/6)

Maybe there is a simpler approach for that.